# json keep pushing in first array item

Tags: javascript

i have hidden input type and i want to push json array in it on click and append with already existing for that i have tried following code

input

```
document.getElementById('addQuestionbtn').onclick = function () {
    const questionData = [];

    let questionJSON = document.getElementById('quesionDataJson');
    if (questionJSON.value.length) {
        let value = JSON.parse(questionJSON.value);
        questionData.push(value)

    }

    let question = document.getElementsByName('question')[0].value;
    let option1 = document.getElementsByName('option1')[0].value;
    let option2 = document.getElementsByName('option2')[0].value;
    let option3 = document.getElementsByName('option3')[0].value;
    let option4 = document.getElementsByName('option4')[0].value;
    let selectedOption = document.querySelector('input[name="options"]:checked').value;

    let data = {
        question: question,
        option1: option1,
        option2: option2,
        option3: option3,
        option4: option4,
        selectedOption: selectedOption
    };
    questionData.push(data);
    questionJSON.value = JSON.stringify(questionData);

};
```

i have form and with input type and btn name as i have used in js now what i am getting is

[image]

now my question is why it is not pushing like below and what i am doing wrong ?

```
[{question: "one", option1: "1", option2: "2", option3: "3", option4: "4"}, 
 {question: "one", option1: "1", option2: "2", option3: "3", option4: "4"}, 
 {question: "one", option1: "1", option2: "2", option3: "3", option4: "4"}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 questionData.push(value)
```

This pushes the array you want to get into the array, might just either append the data:

```
questionData.push(...value);
```

or just re set questionData:

```
questionData = value;
```

Comment: awesome man you saved my day it worked and i got it now why it wasnt working

Comment: @richerd glad to help :)